# Is there a way to store in a variable the value returned from a prepared statement in a Stored Procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
    DELIMITER  $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE prepared_return_value(IN columnName varchar(20), IN tableName varchar(20), IN rowIndex varchar(10))
    BEGIN
    SET @columnName = '';
    SET @columnName = CONCAT('Select distinct ',columnName ,' from ', tableName, ' LIMIT ', rowIndex, ',', '1', ';');
    -- SELECT @columnName;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @columnName;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

So, i'm trying to dynamic pivoting a table using prepared statements to return the unique value of the rows and use it to alter a table.
But for that, i need to be able to store the returned row value, so i can use it in another prepared statement as the column name.
Apparently i can't store the value from the execution of prepared statement neither from a procedure.
I've tried lot of things by know, but none seemed to work, só... any hint on that?

Comment: Can't you use `SELECT ... INTO variable` in the prepared statement?

Comment: i've checked it out, and it worked, thank you so much, i've made some adaptation to fit in the way i was implementing

Answer (score 0):

The Varoable is session bound, so you can be used **after** the procedure has run .

SELECT @columnName

direct after the running outside if the procedure.

another option s to use an `OUT` Parameter besides the `IN`

Ypu would run

```
CALL return_value(columnName, tableName, rowIndex, @columnName)
```

And the crete procedure wil look like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prepared_return_value(IN columnName varchar(20), IN tableName varchar(20), IN rowIndex varchar(10), OUT myoutput TEXT
```

Still what you are doing is highly problematic as it could be used for sql injection, so you should white list colu,nname an Tablename

Comment: i've just made it and it worked like a charm. 
i will be carefull with the Sql Injection issue. 
thank you so much for your response.